# COUNTIF to Ignore Certain Datetime Values

Tags: excel, countif

I have a table with 2 columns, one with datetimes and the other with int values. I also have one cell with a target value in it.

I have a formula counting the number of times the target is exceeded e.g. `=COUNTIF(B:B,">"&G2)`, however I now need to have this formula ignore values where the TIME in the adjacent datetime cell is between two times e.g. `1pm - 2pm` (the date is irrelevant).

Any ideas on how I can either:

- adjust the formula to do this, or
- easily find and delete rows with the unwanted times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a helper column `C` containing the formula:

```
=HOUR(A1)=13
```

Then, in the cell you are using for the count, use the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,">"&G2,C:C,TRUE)
```

Comment: @steviemac2000 You're welcome - please mark the answer as the solution if appropriate, so that the question may be closed. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Add helper column `C` and try this:

```
=IF(OR(C2>=13,C2<=14),"",COUNTIF(B:B,">"&G2))
```